# sf2 instance of Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection given

Tags: symfony, file-upload, collections, persistent

I'm new in php and symfony
I use a file service for the upload in symfony 2.8
I got 2 tables One Salon to many Files

I can upload multiple files in my newaction.
The problem happened at the editAction of my SalonController.

I would like to remove the older files in order to add newfiles in my editfiles.html.twig. And I tried a foreach in order to get this array...

Could you help me please ?

Here is the error

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to DefaultBundle\Service\FileService::upload() must be an instance of DefaultBundle\Entity\File, instance of Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection given, called in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/src/SalonBundle/Controller/SalonController.php on line 131

And the stack trace focused on the line 18 of the fileservice.php

> public function upload(File $file = null, $type) {

Here is the my newaction and editaction of my SalonController

```
class SalonController extends Controller
```

{
    /**
     * Creates a new salon entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="salon_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_SALON');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $salon = new Salon();

```
    $options = array('role' => $this->getUser()->getRoles(), 'page' => 'add');

    $form = $this->createForm( 'SalonBundle\Form\SalonType',$salon, $options);
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $uploadService = $this->get('app.file');

        $myFiles = $form->get('file')->getData();

        foreach($myFiles['path'] as $new_file) {

            $file = new File();
            $file->setPath($new_file);
            $file->setSalon($salon);
            $salon->addFile($file);
            $uploadService->upload($file, 'salon');
            $em->persist($file);
        }

        $user->setSalon($salon);
        $salon->setEnable(false);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->persist($salon);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('email')->salon($salon);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('salon_show', array('id' => $salon->getId()));
    }
```

> ```
> /**
>  * Displays a form to edit an existing salon entity.
>  *
>  * @Route("/edit", name="salon_edit")
>  * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
>  * @Security("has_role('ROLE_SALON')")
>  */
> public function editAction(Request $request)
> {
>     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
>     $user = $this->getUser();
>     $salon = $user->getSalon();
>     $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($salon);
> ```

```
    $options = array('role' => $this->getUser()->getRoles(), 'page' => 'edit');

    $editForm = $this->createForm('SalonBundle\Form\SalonType', $salon, $options);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        // If new file
        $edit_file = $editForm->get('edit_file')->getData();
        if (!is_null($edit_file)) {
            $file_current = $salon->getFiles();
            $salon->getFiles($edit_file);
            if (!$this->get('app.file')->upload($salon->getFiles(), 'salon'))
                $salon->getFiles($file_current);
        }

        foreach($edit_file['path'] as $new_edit_file) {
            $file = new File();
            $file->setPath($new_edit_file);
            $file->setSalon($salon);
            $salon->addFile($file);
            $this->get('app.file')->upload($file);
            $em->persist($file);
        }

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Le partenaire a bien été modifié');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('salon_show');
    }

    return $this->render('@Salon/salon/edit.html.twig', array(
        'salon' => $salon,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}

    return $this->render('@Salon/salon/new.html.twig', array(
        'salon' => $salon,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

A portion of my SalonType

```
    class SalonType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $page = $options['page'];

        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Nom du salon'
            ))
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Descriptif'
            ))
            ->add('address_salon', AddressType::class, array(
                'label' => ' '
            ))
        ;

        if($page == 'add') {
            $builder
                ->add('file', FileType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Vous pouvez téléchargez jusqu\'à 3 images',
                    'required' => false,
                    'mapped' =>false,
                ));
        }

        if($page == 'edit') {
            $builder
                ->add('edit_file', FileType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Nouveau fichier',
                    'required' => false,
                    'mapped' => false
                ));
        };

    }



    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'SalonBundle\Entity\Salon',
            'role' => null
        ));
        $resolver
            ->setRequired(['page']);
    }


My fileType

    class FileType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('path', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Image',
                'multiple' => true,
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null,
        ));
    }
}

My fileService

    <?php
namespace DefaultBundle\Service;

use DefaultBundle\Entity\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class FileService {
    private $directory_root;
    private $directory_default;


    public function __construct($directory_root, $directory_default) {
        $this->directory_root = $directory_root;
        $this->directory_default = $directory_default;
    }

    public function upload(File $file = null, $type) {
        $path = $this->getDirectory($type);

        if (is_null($file))
            return false;

        // Get file (Class UploadFile)
        $file_uploaded = $file->getPath();

        if ($file_uploaded->getError())
            return false;

        // Move file
        $file_name = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file_uploaded->guessExtension();
        $file_uploaded->move($this->directory_root . $path, $file_name);

        // Update object file
        $path .= '/' . $file_name;
        $file->update($file_uploaded, $path);

        return true;
    }

    public function delete(File $file){
        $path = $this->directory_root.$file->getPath();
        if(file_exists($path))
            unlink($path);
    }

    private function getDirectory($type) {
        switch ($type) {
            default:
                return $this->directory_default;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of your upload() method?

Comment: I add the upload method in my question. Thk

Answer (score 1):

Your code is kinda messy, by that I mean you have lot of logic in your controller :-)

Just to know which line is the 131 in your controller?

You have an error here (don't know if it's the 131 line)

```
if (!$this->get('app.file')->upload($salon->getFiles(), 'salon'))
```

Here you send a collection to `upload()`, you said it yourself

> One Salon to many Files

BUT before trying to hotfix this look at is tutorial [here](https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2015/07/manage-multiple-files-upload-in-symfony/) on how to handle multiple file upload.

Also this tutorial has the [full demo source code](https://github.com/harijoe/symfony-vagrant-up/tree/POC-multiple-files-upload/src/AppBundle) available. The code is quite clear and you should be able to understand it easily.

**Edit**

If you don't want to rewrite your code you may want to hotfix your code like that

```
if (!is_null($edit_file)) {
    $file_current = $salon->getFiles();
    //$salon->getFiles($edit_file); What is the goal of this?
    foreach ($salon->getFiles() as $file) {
        // Note that now we send a single File object not a collection
        if (!$this->get('app.file')->upload($file, 'salon')) {
            $salon->setFiles($file_current); // You want to set the files no?
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is 200% ugly, and I'm not even sure if it will work. You should really think about refactoring your code.

**Edit 2**

The problem you have now is that you are mixing your `File` object and the `UploadedFile` object from symfony.

You do `$file_uploaded = $file->getPath();` then you have the error

> Call to a member function getError() on string

and it's normal because `getPath()` return a string.

I assume you have look the [Uploader Service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html#creating-an-uploader-service) of the symfony doc. You can see they pass an `UploadedFile` object which is part of the symfony package, not a custom entity.

If I wanted to do a quick fix, which is definitely not what I recommend, I'll do something like this

```
// Your controller (newAction)
foreach($myFiles['path'] as $new_file) {
    // $new_file is an uploadedFile object, this is the file you want to upload
    $file = new File();
    $file->setPath($new_file);
    $file->setSalon($salon);
    $salon->addFile($file);
    $uploadService->upload($file, $new_file, 'salon');
    $em->persist($file);
}

// Your FileService
public function upload(File $file = null, UploadedFile $file_uploaded = null, $type) {
    $path = $this->getDirectory($type);

    if (is_null($file_uploaded) || is_null($file))
        return false;

    // Get file (Class UploadFile), No here you get the file path => a string
    //$file_uploaded = $file->getPath();

    if ($file_uploaded->getError())
        return false;

    //... end of your method
}
```

Comment: Thk. I saw this tuto, and the upload metho it's not a service, and when I read the comment, there is a lot of mistake. yes the line 131 is this `if (!$this->get('app.file')->upload($salon->getFiles(), 'salon'))`. Do you understand the error ?

Comment: You can easily take their upload() method and use it in a service, you just need some changes on your entitiy(ies). The error is that you try to upload  a collection. Look at my edit

Comment: thk, I passed the first error @Dfayet. The next error now is "Call to a member function getError() on string". and the stack trace focused on the line 26 of my FileService `
        if ($file_uploaded->getError())
            return false;` 
Yes in fact I prefer to avoid to rewrite the total code...

Comment: Thank for your help ! in fact it works with my actual editAction ! I don't know very why. I just add the parameter $salon in `$this->get('app.file')->upload($file, $salon);`. Now I have another pb for register my file in my registerAction.... I have to make a new question ?

Comment: If it is not related to the current question, I think so.